# Jsoup connect with url with special chars

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I try this code to download the source code of a page but it make a 404 error, but when I put it in a navigator it works

```html
org.jsoup.Connection req = Jsoup.connect("http://www.3mfrance.fr/3M/fr_FR/notre-societe-fr/tous-les-produits-3M/~/Colle-structurale-%C3%A9poxyde-3M-Scotch-Weld-DP190?N=5002385+8709320+8710676+8710815+8711017+8711736+8713609+3293242432&rt=rud");
      
      Response rep=req.execute();
      String codeSource= rep.body();
```

Comment: This works on my machine. What IDE are you using? Maybe the java file encoding is wrong. I'm using Eclipse, text file encoding is 'Cp1252'.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, code works as intended. What version of jsoup are you using?

Comment: Do you connect internet directly, or behind a proxy?